# Update a TextFormField inside a StreamController in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Inside a StreamBuilder, I try to display a TextFormField with a value coming from a REST API.

The stream is triggered and hasData is true

Issue is that the value inside the TextFormField is not updated from the data coming from the stream.

I have tested 2 methods:

- setting initialValue with value coming from the stream
- using a textController (set as a class property) and use .text()

In both cases, the value is not updated

Comment: Could you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

After some time en tests, it works with the textController solution.